# c#: how to programmatically highlight/delete rows from datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

i have the results of a query being dumped into a datagridview. it looks like this:

```
QC3 498.46
QC4 1,251.63
QC1 862.62
QC2 1,432.21
```

i need two things

1. to be able able to programmatically delete all the rows of datagrid where the second field = `862.62` (or just delete the third row)
2. i need to programmtically HIGHLIGHT and scroll down to the row to show the user where the first field is `QC4` and the second one is  `1,251.63`

Comment: Is it databound?  If so, delete from the source.

Comment: @i do not want to delete from the source

Comment: Excuse the brevity, I meant the Binding Source.

Comment: @austin i do not want to delete the source data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *to be able able to programmatically delete all the rows of datagrid where the second field = 862.62*

```
var rowsToRemove = from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows
                    where r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "862.62"  // use whatever conversion is appropriate here
                    select r;

foreach (var r in rowsToRemove)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(r);
```

To delete a row at a specific index, call `RemoveAt`:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(2);
```

> *i need to programmtically HIGHLIGHT and scroll down to the row to show the user where the first field is QC4 and the second one is 1,251.63*

Find the row you want to select, then set the `Selected` property and `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property:

```
rowToSelect.Selected = true;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowToSelect.Index;
```

Comment: im sorry can u help me once more with this rowToSelect.Selected = true;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowToSelect.Index;

Comment: @i am a girl, sure -- what do you need help with?  determining the row to select?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example - it needs some work but its a point in the right direction I think.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Prop1="QC1",Prop2="1.000"});
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Prop1 = "QC2", Prop2 = "2.000" });
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Prop1 = "QC3", Prop2 = "3.000" });
        list.Add(new TestClass() { Prop1 = "QC4", Prop2 = "4.000" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;


    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        public TestClass()
        {

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value == "QC3" && row.Cells[1].Value == "3.000")
                row.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

I  hope this helps :)

Comment: and before anyone flames me I know the data types are wrong and not very efficient etc... but for a small recordset should be fine

Comment: is it possible to have a list as datasource? if not can you fix it because i want to user your exmaple

Comment: Yes you can use a list as a datasource :) the above code does work if you create a new datagridview and a button.

Comment: and to delete you could just cheat and use row.Visible = false; in place of row.Selected = true; ;-)